# How to encrypt existing MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

Our company needs to scramble the confidential data first before they send it to us for PHP development. They're asking us what's the best approach to this kind of situation.

The requirement is that the data must be decrypted.

Is there a free/commercial tool to do this or it can be done by PHP or Linux command only?

Comment: Transfer the data over SSH or SSL, or encrypt it with PGP and send it over any connection.

Comment: I would like to encrypt certain fields only in some tables with the capability to decrypt it. Thanks. I will look about PGP encryption.

Comment: It's easier to encrypt the entire thing, assuming you're transferring a database from one place to another.  And **of course** you'd have the capability to decrypt it, if you didn't, then that's not encryption, that's destruction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL already includes reversible [encryption functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html), such as AES_ENCRYPT().

You can scramble sensitive data on a column-by-column basis in the following way:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET sensitive_column = AES_ENCRYPT(sensitive_column, 'password');
```

This works at least for string data.

Comment: The thought of encrypting using AES yet with the feeble strength of a password is amusing, but +1 anyway :)

Comment: @Patashu, it was just an example, I don't suggest using a password that is literally 'password'.  Likewise I assume the table is not literally named `SomeTable`.  :-)

Comment: Thanks. It works. They will have to manually do this for their confidential data before sending us the encrypted one. They shouldn't encrypt the IDs that are going to be used to connect the datables though :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me based on the requirements one wouldn't really want to encrypt the data per se.  One would likely want to mask the data, meaning eg. changing the values in the tables from a real name, address, phone-number to a new fictitious value for the purpose of development and application testing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking